# Cant find Element with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

im trying to click the selected Element out of the HTML List.
[HTML List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJjQZ.png)

This is my code so far but I cant get it to work.

```js
await page.click('.lhggkp7q.ln8gz9je.rx97191a[style^="z-index: 1"]')
```

Any help what I can change? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You likely need to wait for the page to fully load before you select your element. I don't know the function off the top of my head but I know that's a thing.

Comment: That's just a guess (albeit a good/reasonable one). For all we know, this whole screenshot is buried in an iframe or a shadow root. OP needs to show a [mcve] of the page and the code to get reliable help without answerers making guesses. Even if the guesses happen to be correct, it's of little use to future visitors without a reproduction of the original problem.

Comment: If you expand element children in the shared image then I will help you to build a selector for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
await page.click('_3uIPm WYyr1 :nth-child(10)')
```

This selects the 10th child of the parent element you are trying to target.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by digging a bit deeper and clicking a very specific Part of the one i wanted to click originaly

Answer (score -1):

I would advise you to use XPATH element lookup

```
const [xpathElement] = await page.$x(XPATH);
await xpathElement.click();
```

[image]